# New css definition doesn't get applied from linked stylesheet

Tags: html, css

In the head of the document:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resources/css/lessons-matching-test.css"/>
```

In the body of the document

```
<div class="tests">
  <a href="" style="display: block;">Link</a>
</div>
```

In the linked css stylesheet I added this new style

```
.tests
{
     background-color: blue;
     /* some stuff */
}
```

Why isn't my style being applied when I add `class=tests` to my div?

Comment: You don't have to restart your system, just use CTRL+F5 :)

Comment: Please put your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Have you tried using the browsers' developer tools to track down where is the `div` getting it's styling information? (IE, Firefox, chrome have this, press F12 to open it)

Comment: your code is working man ok

Comment: I refresh it, but it's still not working, I use CoffeeCup Free HTML Editor.

Comment: your problem is not with this code. put all your codes in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I create a new HTML-file and insert your code (without the external css and js files) I get the expectated result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><!-- Forgot the quotes -->
<head>
    <meta class="metatype" content="matching-test">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .tests
        {
             background-color: blue;
             /* some stuff */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tests">
        <a href="" style="dispaly: block;">Link</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens when you exclude the js files and/or the css file?

Answer (score 1):

Two cases

1. your lessons.js is doing something with .tests

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/resources/js/libs/lessons.js"></script>
   ```
2. Your css set .tests as important so that you cannot change

   ```
   <link   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resources/css/lessons-matching-test.css"/>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your old styles are being used due to caching. Your new styles do not show up because the browser is using the old styles. There are a couple ways to go about fixing or changing this.

The technique for avoiding that is called "cache busting". When a server side handler is involved this can be handled in a higher language. But if there is no access to one, then usually version names are used.

```
lessons-matching-test-v1.css
```

Naming your css file this way every time you make a change will allow that new version to be used and cached. Ever version, you would increment the number, so version 2 would be lessons-matching-test-v2.css.

Another approach is to attach a query string to the path every time you make a new version

```
href="css/resources/css/lessons-matching-test.css?v=1.0"
```

and then every time you make a new version, change the query string, so version 2 would be `href="css/resources/css/lessons-matching-test.css?v=2.0"`